# How to configure GitHub Pages to skip a file that breaks the Jekyll build?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have some systems that automatically write .md to _posts/.

As you know, below the YAML front matter begins the HTML, in these cases it is arbitrary HTML coming from external sources, which sometimes breaks the build.  This is all via the GitHub API and at some scale so manually deleting the post is not an option.

Is there a way to configure or programmatically interact with Jekyll or GitHub Pages to ignore files or commits that break the build?

If it helps: This is best effort, stability is more important than integrity.  Each post is added in a separate commit, of course Jekyll build does not necessarily run on each commit, but in any case it would be fine to just drop all posts for example by rolling back all commits since the last successful build.

Answer (score 1):

The `_drafts` folder might be of use to you if you have posts that are unfinished. See [the documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/drafts/).

In terms of ignoring posts that break the build, is there no way to locally test the Markdown-to-HTML conversion before pushing to GitHub Pages?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Continuous Integration (CI) service with github](https://github.com/marketplace/category/continuous-integration) (most have free plans).

The idea is to :

- Commit your automatic extracts in a development branch.
- Push this development branch on github.
- Have Continuous Integration service build the branch and take action depending on the build result.

Depending on CI build success/error, you can choose to :

- merge in master for publication is everything went ok
- send you a mail if a branch build fails
- make your site say hello world if result is 42